# Can we create a single access token which has permission for accessing both Azure Blob and Azure Service Bus

Tags: azure-functions

Can we create a single access token that has permission for accessing both Azure Blob and Azure Service Bus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, these 2 types of resources use different audiences (or tokens if you are not going to use Azure AD auth), so its not possible